# Java ProcessBuilder unable to run shell script: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: java, windows, bash

I have a shell script which takes in an argument and prints to file `Logone.txt`:

```
name=$1
log_file="Logone.txt"

if [[ -n "$name" ]]; then
    echo "$1" >> ${log_file}
else
    echo "argument error"
fi
```

This works when tested using GitBash . Example below giving `666` as argument.:

```
 ~/Documents/Documents/rt-wizard/source
  bash pm2_StopStart.bash 666
```

---

I am now trying to do the same thing from within Java code using `ProcessBuilder`.

```
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", "pm2_StopStart.bash");
        Process p = pb.start();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

This gives an error:

> CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Script `pm2_StopStart.bash` is located in `~/Documents/Documents/rt-wizard/source` and program is also being run from the same directory.

Comment: Either drop the `"-c"` argument while constructing the  ProcessBuilder, or replace the `"pm2_StopStart.bash"` with `"./pm2_StopStart.bash"`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin, I get the same response when removing the `"-c"` argument as you suggest